# React Bind to const outside Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to call  this.toggleModal from outside the class in the const MatchNotScoredAlert does not work. It is passed in from onClick to be called by the link. How do I bind it correctly to have call the toggleModal() function inside the class?

```
const MatchNotScoredAlert = ({ onClick }) => (
     <div className="alert alert-grey m-l-10 m-r-10">
      <div className="d-inline-block">
        <h4 className="m-0">Match Not Scored</h4>
      </div>
      <a className="pull-right dark-icon d-inline-block" onClick={onClick} style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>
        <span className="glyphicons glyphicons-exclamation-sign" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );


class Match extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      modal: false,
    };
  }
  toggleModal(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      data: { match },
    } = this.props;
    const {
      division: { contacts },
    } = match;

    return (
      <Container>
        <PageTitle>Matchup:</PageTitle>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Matchup</title>
        </Helmet>
        <MatchHeader match={match} />
        {!match.isScored && <MatchNotScoredAlert onClick={this.toggleModel} />})
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: you have a typo in `onClick={this.toggleModel}`, it should be `onClick={this.toggleModal}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo:

```js
toggleModal(e) {
  ...
}

<MatchNotScoredAlert onClick={this.toggleModel} />
```

replace 'e' with 'a'

Comment: You should mark such question as off topic since they are not really helpful for future readers

Comment: damn, yea that would be it. Thanks. I will mark it off topic